# jQuery FullCalendar: Disable scrolling in Agenda View?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

How can I disable scrolling in the Agenda View (week, day mode) using the FullCalendar jQuery plug-in? In month mode everything is fine, but when I change to Week/Day mode there is a scrollbar next to my mainpage scrollbar.

Comment: In looking through the documentation, I don't see any way to disable scrolling in a certain view. Maybe provide an example of your code to see if there is a way to prevent this in your HTML/CSS.

Comment: I just see that when I use basicWeek and basicDay instead of agendaWeek and agendaDay there is no scrollbar, so I guess the scrollbar is a 'feature' for the agendaWeek en agendaDay Views.

Comment: you cannot reove it without hacking the js file. The height of the calendar is set to be proportional to the width and the width is set based on the amount of div width available. The proportion sets the height and makes everything else hidden and scrollable within the perimeter. I am not sure where it is set in the js but that is where it will have to be changed. Wish I could be more help!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This was what I did in my case.
The goal is to dynamically change the height, so I used the viewDisplay event in that way:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    viewDisplay: function (view) {
        var h;
        if (view.name == "month") {
            h = NaN;
        }
        else {
            h = 2500;  // high enough to avoid scrollbars
        }

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'contentHeight', h);
    }
});
```

Comment: [`viewDisplay`](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/removed/viewDisplay/) has been deprecated

Comment: Anyone please suggest a solution for dynamic height. I have a dynamic data which initializes agenda view, So it not possible for me to set some specific height e.g 2500 in my view. in some cases content won't fit and in some other case there may come plently of extra space in my view.

Comment: also setting the height to 'auto' did not work for me in FullCalendar v2.1.1

Answer (score 17):

Starting from FullCalendar 2.1.0-beta1, you can set `{ height: 'auto' }` option to disable scrollbars in views.

Although changelog entry for this new functionality can be read as "To turn scrollbars off in month view", it actually works for all views.

> In month view, when the calendar's height overflows because of too many events, vertical scrollbars will appear. To turn this behavior off, set the height option to 'auto'. -- [from v2.1.0-beta1 changelog](https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar/releases/tag/v2.1.0-beta1)

Comment: If I set to height to auto in FullCalendar 3.5.1, the month view is perfect, but the agenda height is cut off and a vertical scroll bar appears.

Answer (score 6):

just use:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    height: "auto"
});
```

Comment: Already included in an answer above (http://stackoverflow.com/a/25440372/219324).

Answer (score 3):

Sure

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    height: 999999999
});
```

If your calendar has a scrollbar when you don't want it to then you have 3 options:

1. make it big enough that it won't have a scroll bar
2. shrink the content so that it fits within your coundaries
3. remove the scrollbar and lose access to the information not shown

You need to be more specific than "I don't like scroll bars"

Comment: Thanks, the height property indeed removes the scrollbar in the agendaDay and agendaWeek, but now the month view is cropped and looks aweful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated and shortened version of @Deulis answer:

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
  viewRender: function(view){
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar("option", "contentHeight", (view.name === "month")? NaN : 9999);
  }
});
```

As @Pierre de LESPINAY and @Jens-André Koch already mentioned, [viewDisplay](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs1/removed/viewDisplay/) is depricated in fullcalendar v2.0. We have to use [viewRender](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/viewRender/) instead.

Comment: Shorter still: `viewRender: function(view) { $('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'contentHeight', (view.name === 'month') ? NaN : 99999); }` :-)